# Unknown entity: com.netbanking.Users

Tags: hibernate

When I run the following code, I get the error `Unknown entity: com.netbanking.Users`

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
      System.out.println("Hello World!!");  
      Session session=HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
      session.beginTransaction();
      Users users=new Users();
      users.setUsername("Venkat");
      users.setPassword("vairam");

      session.save(users);
      session.getTransaction().commit();
      session.close();
      HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post ur config files, full stack trace. Usually you get this exception when you have not configured users properly

Comment: Please, add `HibernateUtilities` and specify the Hibernate version too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using annotations make sure you have `@Entity` on top of `User` class. If not check if there is a user.hbm.xml file having `<class name="com.netbanking.Users" table="users>"`.

Also, in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file see if there is a mapping for `com.netbanking.Users`. You should have either `<mapping resource="users.hbm.xml" />` or `<mapping class="com.netbanking.Users" />` depending on whether you're using xml or annotations for binding.